# Printing strings in LC-3 assembly language (super noob)

Tags: string, assembly, lc3

Super noob here. I'm doing a "hello world" type program in LC-3 assembly language and I simply don't know how to print more than one string to the console. I need 4 strings on separate lines that are my class, name, project and goodbye. Right now all I can seem to print in the class.

```
       .ORIG x3000
LOOP   LEA R0, CLASS
       LD R1, NAME
       LD R2, PROJECT
       LD R3, GOODBYE
       PUTS
       HALT
CLASS .STRINGZ "CS101\n"
NAME  .STRINGZ "JOHN\n"
...
      .END
```

How would I get the other 3 to print? Thanks!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The `Z` in `.STRINGZ` means zero terminated. That is you have declared separate strings. If you want to print them all, you need to invoke `PUTS` multiple times. Alternatively, make it a single string with embedded newlines. Then you can print the whole thing in one go.